# PHP or Laravel Helper Function to Collect Variables Into Array

Tags: php, laravel

I vaguely remember there being a PHP or Laravel helper function that collects variables into a named array, using the variable names as the array keys.

What was the name of that function again?

With

```
$foo = 1;
$bar = 2;
```

this call

```
some_function($foo, $bar);
```

would return

```
[
    "foo" => 1,
    "bar" => 2
]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`compact()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php):

```
compact('foo', 'bar');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `combine()`

The `combine` method combines the keys of the collection with the values of another array or collection:

```
$collection = collect(['name', 'age']);

$combined = $collection->combine(['George', 29]);

$combined->all();

// ['name' => 'George', 'age' => 29]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP function array_combine please visit these link [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

```
$array_key = ['name','age'];

$array_value = ['George', 29];

$final_array = array_combine($array_key,$array_value);
```

you will get final result

```
[
    "name" => "George",
    "age" => 29
]
```

Note :- Both array must be same size of array